# Select all rows after first x rows containing NULLs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I have table `src`. In this table, each Product-Country combination might contain `NULL` in the `Country` column for the first `x` rows.

How can I `SELECT` rows for each Product-Country combination, only rows after the first `x` rows that contain `NULL` in the Country column? It's important to also `SELECT` any latter rows, even if they do contain `NULL` in the Country column, as long as there was at least one row with a true value, prior to it.

**Expected Output**

For example.

1. For product A, I would like to `SELECT` rows with **ID 3 and 4**, but not ID 1 and 2.
2. For Product B, I would like to `SELECT` rows with **ID 6 and 7**, but not ID 5.

| ID | Product | Country | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A | AT | 2022-01-23 14:29:06.830 |
| 4 | A | NULL | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |
| 6 | B | CH | 2022-01-23 14:29:06.830 |
| 7 | B | NULL | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |

**Sample Table and Data**

```
create table dbo.src
(
    ID int not null
    ,Product varchar(2) not null
    ,Country varchar(2) null
    ,[Timestamp] datetime not null
)

insert into dbo.src
    (ID,Product, Country, [Timestamp])
values
    (1,'A',NULL,'2022-01-21 14:29:06.830')
    ,(2,'A',NULL,'2022-01-22 14:29:06.830')
    ,(3,'A','AT','2022-01-23 14:29:06.830')
    ,(4,'A',NULL,'2022-01-24 14:29:06.830')
    ,(5,'B',NULL,'2022-01-22 14:29:06.830')
    ,(6,'B','CH','2022-01-23 14:29:06.830')
    ,(7,'B',NULL,'2022-01-24 14:29:06.830')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create one enumeration per product and one per product, country. By subtracting these two numbers, we get detection of when a product changes the country. Let's call this constructed attribute grp. To handle the case when the first country is not null, we add 1 to grp for these. By filtering out all rows where grp = 0, we get the expected result:

```
select ID, Product, Country, [Timestamp]
from (
  select s.*
       , case when country is not null then 1 else 0 end
       + row_number() over (partition by Product order by [Timestamp]) 
       - row_number() over (partition by Product, country order by [Timestamp]) grp
  from dbo.src s
) as T
where grp > 0
order by product, [Timestamp]
```

| ID | Product | Country | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | AT | 2022-01-22 14:29:06.830 |
| 3 | A | AT | 2022-01-23 14:29:06.830 |
| 4 | A |  | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |
| 6 | B | CH | 2022-01-23 14:29:06.830 |
| 7 | B |  | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |
| 8 | C | CH | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |

[Fiddle2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34d182685e11ebfdf6cf3fbed9d9c9f2)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work. Use a cte to find the first ID for each product that is not null, then join back to the original table.

```
;WITH cMinProductId AS (
    SELECT Product, MIN(ID) MinID
    FROM dbo.src
    WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Product
)
SELECT s.*
FROM dbo.src AS s
INNER JOIN cMinProductId AS mp
    ON s.Product = mp.Product
WHERE s.ID >= mp.MinID
```

| ID | Product | Country | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A | AT | 2022-01-23 14:29:06.830 |
| 4 | A | NULL | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |
| 6 | B | CH | 2022-01-23 14:29:06.830 |
| 7 | B | NULL | 2022-01-24 14:29:06.830 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73fbb278e52578e0289fc5db05d4c052)